# Spring MVC - Map controller to context root (/) while using mvc:resources

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Morning,

Having issues mapping a controller to / (i.e. localhost:8080/someApp/ would map to @Controller("/")) while also using mvc:resources

web.xml mapping:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

mvc:resources

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The server loads the page correctly, but when I map to an asset i.e.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/blueprint/print.css"/>" />
```

When clicking the css file via view-source in a web browser, the server response maps back to the index page, rather than the resource.  Leads me to believe it's related to the servlet-mapping.

Any help with this would be great!

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Forgot to mention, if I bind the controller to say:

```
@Controller("/pages")
```

Everything works fine, just would rather have the context root be able to respond correctly.

Comment: What is your environment? AFAIK Weblogic, for example requires explicit mime mapping of css in web.xml <mime-mapping><extension>css</extension><mime-type>text/css</mime-type></mime-mapping>

Comment: Figured out the problem going to update the post, weird problem, though.

Comment: reupdated the post to show why

Comment: Its a good idea to add your solution as an answer. That way the question is marked as "answered" and thus saves people like me reading through the entire question only to find it is answered at the bottom.

Comment: @nickdos http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186

Comment: Yeah, I can't answer my own question for another couple hours

Comment: Forgot about that gotcha - seems like a bad solution to a problem of poor usability in the first place.

Comment: Putting someones solution down without offering your own answer is quite rude, and not helping the community as a whole.  Please provide your own solution before bashing others.

Comment: Huh? Not sure I follow, how is this not consistent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@Controller("/)
```

and

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

are not the same thing.

Since @RequestMapping may be placed at a class level, placing the mapping on the class will have the desired affect.

Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RootController
{

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String index()
  {
    return "index";
  }

}
```

This will work correctly, and also works with the mvc:resources bean.

Comment: Unfortunately the above does not work for me (Spring 4.3.1). Any other ideas?

Comment: It should still work, my guess is that the controller isn't being picked up due to component scan looking in the wrong packages, or not having component scan at all.  @Controller is just metadata used by Spring to signify to the component scan that it is available for wiring as a bean.  If you do not use component scan, you need to wire the bean manually.

Answer (score -1):

put this line in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean name="/"
      class="com.springapp.mvc.HelloController" />
```

it will work.

mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```